# .htaccess too many redirect error to the same page url

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a very weird too many redirect error on apache server
The site was working for a long time, and there was no change. I woke this morning in this happened.

Apache is working, but from a specific folder it cannot serve even a html file. Browser showing:
`This page isn’t working redirected you too many times.`

I tried to replace to .htaccess of maintenance mode which worked in the past, but even this causing the error.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^members/site/maintenance\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/members/site/maintenance.html [R=307,L]
```

I checked the site with [Redirect Path](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirect-path/aomidfkchockcldhbkggjokdkkebmdll/related?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)
This is what I see:

```
https://example.com/members/site/maintenance.html
307: Temporary redirect to https://example.com/members/site/maintenance.html
https://example.com/members/site/maintenance.html
307: Temporary redirect to https://example.com/members/site/maintenance.html
https://example.com/members/site/maintenance.html
307: Temporary redirect to https://example.com/members/site/maintenance.html
:
:
and so on
```

Any idea what is causing it and how to fix?

Comment: what happene when you remove it?

Comment: It was a database issue. Your answer pointed my to the right direction. Thanks!